# Changing the caption of a label form control in Visio using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visio

I am having an issue with trying to figure out how to change the caption of an existing Text box in Visio. I have tried using `.Text` which doesn't change what's inside the box only the outside. I guess it changes the label of the text box. Now I'm trying to use the Cells Property but I keep getting
An "Unexpected End of File" error. I'm very new to visual basics and I'm not able figure this one out

[What I'm trying to change through Vb.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX3n3.png)

Here is the snippet of code that I'm working with. Would anyone know how to fix this? Perhaps give me some pointers on how.

```
Dim testingShape As Visio.Shape = Application.ActivePage.Shapes("lbltesting")

testingShape.Cells("Prop.Caption").ResultIU = "Date created: " & Application.UserName & " " & Now
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, The terminology is tricky as it depends on what you're refering to when you say _caption_ and _label_.  Do you have a screenshot of the shape and, if it's from a built-in stencil or template, then if you could describe which one, that will help track down the shape.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to get a screenshot of the text box because its invisible. It was a text box that was brought down from the developer insert menu. Thanks for getting back to me on this.

Comment: This code try modify shape `testingShape` [ShapeData cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946400/how-to-get-shape-data-with-vba-in-visio) (also known as Custom Property). When this cell `Prop.Caption` dont exist you get error! At your screenshot I can see not ShapeData window

Answer (score 1):

You can access Form controls on the page via the [OLEObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.oleobjects) collection.  There's a collection at Document, Page and Master levels.

I see you're using vb.net so I'm hoping a translation of a C# example below will be straight forward.

*Note, the reference to `GetRunningVisio` is just my method of getting hold of the application from LINQPad (see [this link](https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html) for more details).*

```
using Forms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

    var vPag = vApp.ActivePage;

    foreach (Visio.OLEObject obj in vPag.OLEObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ProgID: {obj.ProgID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Hosting shape: {obj.Shape.NameID}");
        
        object dataObj = obj.Object;
        
        switch (obj.ProgID)
        {
            case "Forms.Label.1":
                var lbl = dataObj as Forms.Label;
                if(lbl != null)
                    lbl.Caption = "My caption";
                break;
            case "Forms.TextBox.1":
                var txtBox = dataObj as Forms.TextBox;
                if (txtBox != null)
                    txtBox.Text = "My text";
                break;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dataObj);
    }
}
```

Two other points to bear in mind:

- ProgIDs are case sensitive
- The above shows the OLEObjects collection approach, but you can also attack this via the shape first method by iterating the shapes or, if you know the ID, directly via a single shape.  To do this check that the `Shape.Type` is `VisShapeTypes.visTypeForeignObject` and `Shape.ForeignType` is  `VisShapeTypes.visTypeIsOLE2`